# Where are SMS and MMS stored?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, filesystem, phone, mms

I have BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition phone and I'm not able to get MMS.

If someone sends me a MMS, I just get empty message with no sender or anything. I can see those messages in message-app but I'm not able to delete them.

So I wonder if I can delete them straight from file system?

Where are these messages stored?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SMS are stored in `~/.local/share/history-service/history.sqlite` which you can edit with the `sqlite3` tool. I would avoid manipulating this database directly though, as it is not documented whether manipulating this file directly will cause it to lose sync with state that might be stored elsewhere.

Comment: For everybody who is not to familliar with SQLite. With `.tables` you get the tables and with `SELECT * FROM text_events` you get the messages. To quit press `Ctrl+D`

Comment: .schema <tablename> reveals more information about the tables headers and its general structure.